# reboot does not set sshd port

Tags: sshd

I have changed the port for ssh on a debian bullseye system in `sshd_config` with

```
Port 22222
```

and expect that this port is automatically set again after a reboot. On two new installation I find that after reboot `sshd` is started, but the port is set to 22 (default) and not to the one set in the `sshd_config`. I have to

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

to set it to the desired non-default value. I see then for

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 22

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22222           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22222                :::*                    LISTEN
```

does the second entry indicate that ssh is listening to any port?

On other debian bullseye installation this seem not to be necessary.

What is the best procedure to automatically reset the port after reboot?

```
systemctl enable ssh
```

seems not to work (sshd does not work, because it is only an alias for ssh).

I have two systems with exactly the same hardware (raspi4, running debian `Linux gais 5.10.0-10-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.84-1 (2021-12-08) aarch64 GNU/Linux`) and set up the same (with an ansible script) and they behave the same. The `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

Port 22022
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: thank you - it was a typo and I have corrected it.

Comment: Your effect should not be happening in the first place. I can't reproduce it right now, but I might try tomorrow. Restarting the server should force `sshd` to read it's configuration file on startup. So if you indeed changed the config file, saved and rebooted, it *should* be listening on 22222.

Comment: ... this makes me wonder: how do you reboot?

Comment: If you hadn't used `grep`, you would have seen that the header for the 4th column is "Foreign Address", meaning you accept input from any source port of any external address.

Comment: I reboot with `sudo reboot` or switch on power.